# Why is my nav bar (flex-box) not collapsing when I resize the browser window to a smaller size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am tinkering with FlexBox to design my site, and I am trying to apply these techniques to make a responsive and collapsable nav bar (ideally for mobile users). How can I achieve this? Apparently the flex commands in the .nbar class are not working.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  min-width: 960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  /*display:flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  this is just for the night vision button to position better
  */
}
.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*these two at the bottomr are optional to
  center them on the page
  max-width: 960px;
  margin:0 auto;*/
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

/*WE MISSED THE .ONE SELECTOR*/
.one{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.title{
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  top:20px;
}

.header{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  order:0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}
.nav{
  width:100%;
  /*min-width: 900px;*/
  height:40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  order:1;
}
.banner{
  width:100%;
  min-width: 960px;
  height:500px;
  color:white;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  order:3;
}
.boxOne{
  width:45%;
  min-width: 200px;
  height:300px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  order:4;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(120,120,120);
  text-align: justify;
}
.boxTwo{
  width:45%;
  min-width: 200px;
  height:300px;
  order:4;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(120,120,120);
}
.footer{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(120,120,120);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(120,120,120);
  order:5;
}
.nbar{
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: stretch;
flex-flow: wrap;
}
  .two{
    flex-grow: 0;
  }
      .home {
        order:1;
      }
      .services {
        order:2;
      }
      .testimonials {
        order:3;
      }
      .portfolio {
        order:4;
      }
      .contact {
        order:5;
      }
li {
  display:inline-flex;
  padding:10px 40px 10px 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.disc{
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: rgb(150,150,150);
}
.people{
  overflow: hidden;
  height:500px;
  width:960px;
}
/*.popup {
  background-color: white;
  height: 20px;
  width:90px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- dockmann -->
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="one header">
        <p class="title">DOCKMANN</p>
      </div>
      <!-- end header -->
      <div class="one nav">
        <ul class="nbar">
          <li class="two home">
            <a href="www.dockmann.com">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="two services">
            SERVICES
          </li>
          <li class="two testimonials">
            TESTIMONIALS
          </li>
          <li class="two portfolio">
            PORTFOLIO
          </li>
          <li class="two contact">
            CONTACT
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end nav -->
      <div class="one banner">
        <img class="people" src="image/macdesk.jpg" />
      </div>
      <!-- end banner -->
      <div class="one boxOne">
        <h2>Who we are...</h2>
        <br />
        Filler
      </div>
      <!-- end boxOne -->
      <div class="one boxTwo">
        boxTwo
      </div>
      <!-- end boxTwo -->
      <div class="one footer">
      <p class="disc">
      filler
      </p>
      </div>
      <!-- end footer -->

    </div>

    <!-- <button class="popup">
      Night Vision!
    </div> -->
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: min-width and height here and there without any mediaqueries to reset one or  and the other might have to do. what result do you expect ? wrapping into column or a burger like menu ?

Comment: I was expecting the nav items to wrap into a column as the browser size became smaller. Thank you

Comment: okay, look at mediaquerie to reset flex value for li and min-width for .wrapper and .banner. for the 2 col parts, idem , same way to deal with the layout ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like removing `min-width` from `.wrapper` and removing `min-height` from `.nav` bar seems to fix the problem,

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  /*display:flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  this is just for the night vision button to position better
  */
}
.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*these two at the bottomr are optional to
  center them on the page
  max-width: 960px;
  margin:0 auto;*/
  margin: auto;
}

/*WE MISSED THE .ONE SELECTOR*/
.one{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.title{
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  top:20px;
}

.header{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  order:0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}
.nav{
  width:100%;
  /*min-width: 900px;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  order:1;
}
.banner{
  width:100%;
  min-width: 960px;
  height:500px;
  color:white;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  order:3;
}
.boxOne{
  width:45%;
  min-width: 200px;
  height:300px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  order:4;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(120,120,120);
  text-align: justify;
}
.boxTwo{
  width:45%;
  min-width: 200px;
  height:300px;
  order:4;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(120,120,120);
}
.footer{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(120,120,120);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(120,120,120);
  order:5;
}
.nbar{
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: stretch;
flex-flow: wrap;
}
  .two{
    flex-grow: 0;
  }
      .home {
        order:1;
      }
      .services {
        order:2;
      }
      .testimonials {
        order:3;
      }
      .portfolio {
        order:4;
      }
      .contact {
        order:5;
      }
li {
  display:inline-flex;
  padding:10px 40px 10px 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.disc{
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: rgb(150,150,150);
}
.people{
  overflow: hidden;
  height:500px;
  width:960px;
}
/*.popup {
  background-color: white;
  height: 20px;
  width:90px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- dockmann -->
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="one header">
        <p class="title">DOCKMANN</p>
      </div>
      <!-- end header -->
      <div class="one nav">
        <ul class="nbar">
          <li class="two home">
            <a href="www.dockmann.com">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="two services">
            SERVICES
          </li>
          <li class="two testimonials">
            TESTIMONIALS
          </li>
          <li class="two portfolio">
            PORTFOLIO
          </li>
          <li class="two contact">
            CONTACT
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- end nav -->
      <div class="one banner">
        <img class="people" src="image/macdesk.jpg" />
      </div>
      <!-- end banner -->
      <div class="one boxOne">
        <h2>Who we are...</h2>
        <br />
        Filler
      </div>
      <!-- end boxOne -->
      <div class="one boxTwo">
        boxTwo
      </div>
      <!-- end boxTwo -->
      <div class="one footer">
      <p class="disc">
      filler
      </p>
      </div>
      <!-- end footer -->

    </div>

    <!-- <button class="popup">
      Night Vision!
    </div> -->
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As my experience li tag does not work with flex-wrap therefor all of your 'li's

will stay in one line. If you want to solve your problem change this:

```
<ul class='nbar'>
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
</ul>
```

to this:

```
<div class='nbar'>
  <div>menu1</div>
  <div>menu2</div>
</div>
```

It will work. And please do not forget using -webkit- for flex properties because some of mobile browsers only works with this. For example:

```
display:-webkit-flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
```